Why is file not found when running the code and why does it say can not find react
PS C:\Users\JOSEPHINE ARPA\Desktop\TESTING> npm run dev
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall open
npm error path C:\Users\JOSEPHINE ARPA\Desktop\TESTING\package.json
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\JOSEPHINE ARPA\Desktop\TESTING\package.json'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\JOSEPHINE ARPA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-13T02_27_52_848Z-debug-0.log

I was trying the code to see a web page result

Hello, are you sure you in the right folder? if you want to run npm run dev, you need to make sure there's package.json file in the folder that you want to execute. To easily check if there's any package.json file, run ls in your terminal folder, then search for package.json.
